# How to get a value in an array that's in a list of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

To populate a HTML select field, I have this data:

```
let options = [
 {'label': '--Choose--', 'value':''},
 {'label': 'Linux', 'value':'linux'},
 {'label': 'OSX', 'value':'mac'},
 {'label': 'Windows 98', 'value':'win9x'},
 {'label': 'Windows XP', 'value':'winxp'}
]
```

Now with the value 'mac' I'd like to get the label 'OSX'.

Is it possible to get the label based on the value with this array in JSX in an elegant way?

e.g. 'mac' should give 'OSX'

I have ES6/ReactJS/Underscore/jQuery available.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're glad to help you, but we don't just write code for you.

Comment: Use `filter` to find the item where `value=='mac'` then `map` to return value of the `label` key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return a filtered array, grab the first element (which is an object), and then grab the value of `label`.

```
var label = options.filter(el => el.value === 'mac')[0].label;
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1x5com/)

Comment: beat me by 15 seconds :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
let option = options.find(el => el.value === 'mac');
let label = option ? option.label : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the fast replies, I made it a bit more robust for my own usecase, where both 'mac' and options where unsure.
Note the == instead of === because most of the time integers were compared to strings.

```
export function getLabelByValue(value, options) {
  if(value !== '' && value !== null && options.length > 0) {
      return options.filter(el => el.value == value)[0].label
  }
  return ''
}

let label = getLabelByValue('mac', options)
```